# Show $E[\mathrm{Var}(X|Y)]=E[(X-E(X|Y))^2]$.

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. How to show that
>   $$E[\operatorname{Var}(X|Y)]=E[(X-E(X|Y))^2]?$$

I have been able to prove that the statement is equivalent to
$$E(XE(X|Y))=E(E^2(X|Y)),\tag{1}$$
but then I don't know why $(1)$ is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $(1)$, note that $E(XE(X|Y)) = E(E(XE(X|Y)|Y)) = E(E(X|Y)E(X|Y))$

The last equality is because $E(X|Y)$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, we can get it out of $E(\cdot|Y) = $

Comment: Yes I see it now. So many thanks ! :)

Comment: @Rotman Great, you are welcome!